# tcpdf imagebox and cropping

Tags: php, tcpdf

I would like to add a 'imagebox' a box which contains the image and crops exceeding image value that is outside of this box. something like this:

[image]

I am not sure on how to do this if it's even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could crop an image with php , store it as a temp_file pass it to tcpfd and then delete it after the rendering of the pdf was done . Another option would be to use html/css to position a html element over the image but as we all know tcpdf doesn't know too much about css so i don't know if it will work .

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can do this with Clipping.
The below line would show a photo of 200X300:

```
$pdf->Image('photo.JPG', 100, 100, 200, 300, '', true, '', false, 300);
```

To clip it you need:

```
$pdf->StartTransform();
$pdf->Rect(100, 100, 200, 300, 'CNZ'); //Clipping mask (CNZ style makes your day)
$pdf->Image('photo.JPG', 50, 50, 300, 400, '', true, '', false, 300);
//this would actually cut off a 50 units a in each direction.
$pdf->StopTransform();
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I should add, that you can even crop rotated images
`$pdf->StartTransform();
$pdf->Rotate(15, $centerXmm, $centerYmm);
$pdf->Rect(0, 0, 150, 300, 'CNZ');
$pdf->Image('@'.$imgdata, $imageLeftMM, $imageTopMM, $imageWidthMM, $imageHeightMM);
$pdf->StopTransform();`